# Adding a remove button in my item list

Tags: java, android

I am fairly new to Java and Android development. I am currently creating a shopping app and was looking at adding a "Remove" button to my Shopping Cart list.

Here is my current code for my list activity for my shopping cart, I am not really sure where to begin and some guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```
package .shopper;

import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class CartListActivity extends ListActivity {

    public class ProductListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private final Context context;

        private List<Product> itemList;

        public List<Product> getItemList() {
            return itemList;
        }

        public void setItemList(List<Product> itemList) {
            this.itemList = itemList;
        }

        public Context getContext() {
            return context;
        }

        public ProductListAdapter(Context c) {
            context = c;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() { 
            if(itemList == null) return 0;
            else return itemList.size();
        }       

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) { 
            if (itemList == null) return null;
            else return itemList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) { 
            if (itemList == null) return 0;
            else return itemList.get(position).hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View cell = convertView;

            if (cell == null) {
                // get layout from mobile xml
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
                cell = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_product_list, parent, false);
            }

            Product p = itemList.get(position);

            //set value into textview according to position
            TextView textView = (TextView) cell.findViewById(R.id.product_title);
            textView.setText(p.getProductName());

            // add £ symbol
            textView = (TextView) cell.findViewById(R.id.product_info);
            textView.setText("Price: " + "£"+ p.getPrice());  

            //set value into imageview according to position
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) cell.findViewById(R.id.product_image);
            // clear the image
            imgView.setImageDrawable(null);
            //and load from the network
            p.loadImage(imgView, 54, 54);           

            return cell;
        }

    }

    public static final Integer[] productIcons = {
        0, // index 0 is empty
        R.drawable.books,
        R.drawable.films,
        R.drawable.music,
        R.drawable.games,
    };

    private int categoryId;
    private ProductListAdapter adapter;
    private ListViewLoader loader;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // get the category from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        categoryId = intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.SELECTED_CATEGORY, 0);

        adapter = new ProductListAdapter(this);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        setupActionBar();

        loader = new ListViewLoader(adapter, categoryId);
        loader.execute(String.format(MainActivity.WEBSERVER_GETLIST, categoryId));
    }

    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}.
     */
    private void setupActionBar() {

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.product_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.show_cart:
            //create the intent for the cart activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CartActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        //create an intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProductActivity.class);
        Product p = (Product)adapter.getItem(position);
        //specify the extra parameters we want to pass
        intent.putExtra(MainActivity.SELECTED_CATEGORY, p.getCategoryId());
        intent.putExtra(MainActivity.SELECTED_PRODUCTID, p.getProductId());
        intent.putExtra(MainActivity.SELECTED_PRODUCTNAME, p.getProductName());
        intent.putExtra(MainActivity.SELECTED_PRODUCTPRICE, p.getPrice());
        intent.putExtra(MainActivity.SELECTED_SUITABLEFORKIDS, p.getSuitableForKids());

        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

EDIT:
XML for adapter_product_list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/product_image"
        android:layout_width="54dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/product_image"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/product_image"
        android:textColor="#446688"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/product_image"
        android:layout_below="@+id/product_title"
        android:textColor="#777777"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Then whats problem explain?

Comment: I am not sure how to implement a remove button... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) hope p.loadImage(imgView, 54, 54);  is running in a asyncTask
2) if you want to click on a button in a row of a ListView than you shoudl add the button to your row layout and implent onClickListenr of that button in your getView method of adapter.in onClick method yous hould have:

```
if(position<itemList.size()){
       //TO REMOVE TEM FROM ARRAY LIST
      itemList.remove(position);
      //TO Update the ListView
      notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

you can implement a multy line delete,by adding a checkbox in your listRow and adding the positon of the item to be deleted to an arrayList of Integers and after click-ing the delete button you should delete all the items from the imteList and after that call notifyDataSetChanged()

**EDIT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="8dp">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/product_image"
    android:layout_width="54dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/product_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/product_image"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/product_image"
    android:textColor="#446688"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/product_info"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/product_image"
    android:layout_below="@+id/product_title"
    android:textColor="#777777"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="italic" />
 <Button 
    android:id="@+id/deleteBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/product_info"
 </RelativeLayout>
```

you should add this button to your layout, and in getView method of adapter add

```
Button delete=v.findViewById(R.id.deleteBtn);
delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
       @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //THE PART I WROTE ABOVE
    }     
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, p.loadImage is running an asynctask.Adding the button to the layout and implementing the onClickListener is fine, Do i put the code above in the onListItemClick method? thanks, i am getting errors.

Comment: in your getItem() of the Adapter class you should add onClickListener for the button that you will use to delete the row.

Comment: Thanks for all the help and the edits, i do appreciate your time. I am putting the code you gave me at the end of getView (and i have tried other places in getView) but I am getting lots of errors such as Button and v cannot be resolved. thanks again

Comment: it's all about imports you should add to your class. you can try not to copy/paste the code bot rewrite it in your getView method and change the v.findViewById with cell.findViewById

Comment: P.S. all of this should be before return statement :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your xml like following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/product_image"
        android:layout_width="54dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/product_image"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/product_image"
        android:text="adjkajdjk"
        android:textColor="#446688"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/product_title"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/product_image"
        android:text="adjkajdjk"
        android:textColor="#777777"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Delete" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in your adapter inside getView() function add this

```
Button deleteBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);
        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                itemList.remove(position);  
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
```